# JavaScript being weird in Brackets code editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, adobe-brackets

I'm using JS in brackets, and I'm having some problems. First, the alert property doesn't work. Is this just because of brackets live preview? Second, it doesn't tell me when I've made errors )I entered in nonsensical commands, and there was no errors at all. Also, when I named a variable starting with a number, no error message! These are just problems I noticed in the last 5 minutes. Please help! Here's my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
        document.write("Hello world");
        var someText = " years old";
        var years = 35;
        alert(years + sometext);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: alert will not work because of syntax error. `sometext` is not defined. `someText` is. I am not really sure how you're saying that brackets aren't showing you any errors. You can use the browser, you don't have to use brackets actually. But if you do have plugins which can handle such, then check the plugin

Comment: What do you mean by I use the browser instead of brackets?

Answer (score 3):

You declare your variable as `someText` but then refer to it as `sometext` in your alert:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      document.write("Hello world");
      var someText = " years old";
      var years = 35;
      alert(years + someText); // <--
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```